# How to define a ListBoxItem Template that has the same size of its parent?

Tags: wpf, templates, listboxitem

I am using the following code:

```
<ListBox 
    x:Name="lbItems"            
    Grid.Row="1"
    Margin="2">
    <ListBox.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <Border 
                Background="{StaticResource DarkerBrush}"                            
                Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}, Mode=FindAncestor}}"
                BorderBrush="{StaticResource MediumBrush}"
                BorderThickness="0"
                CornerRadius="4">
                <ItemsPresenter />                            
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ListBox.Template>
</ListBox>
```

it works, but I see an exception in the Output Window that I would like to remove.

> System.Windows.Data Information: 10 :
>   Cannot retrieve value using the
>   binding and no valid fallback value
>   exists; using default instead.
>   BindingExpression:Path=ActualWidth;
>   DataItem=null; target element is
>   'Border' (Name=''); target property is
>   'Width' (type 'Double')

Probably I am doing something not perfectly right, so do you have any idea **how can I improve my code**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Width="{Binding ElementName=lbItems, Path=ActualWidth}" ?
```

Comment: thank you, in this case it solved the problem, but it happens quite frequently also on default controls like ComboBoxItem